# Not able to telnet Cisco Router using Python script

Tags: python

I am trying to login to Cisco switch and run commands in it using python telnetlib script, after running the script it displays "password" in the output terminal for which i enter the switch password and then it hangs.

Note: there is no Username and Password.Enable password only given

```
               import get pass
               import telnet lib
               Host='192.168.0.1'
               password=get pass.get pass()

               tn=telnet lib. Telnet(Host)

               tn.read_until('password:')
               tn.write(password +'\n') 
               tn.write('enable \n')
               tn.write('Cisco \n')
               tn.write('terminal length 0 \n')
               tn.write('sh version \n')
               tn.write('exit \n')
               print tn.read_all()
```

i want to login and get show information from switch using python

Answer (score 0):

I am using PrettyGoodTerminal for python scripting cisco and juniper devices, works for me.
For running simple ios commands, you don!t event need pyton, but if you want to learn python, this is all what thee script you need

```
result = Session.ExecCommand("show version")
```

For a simple tutorial look at [this article](http://prettygoodterminal.blogspot.com/2016/05/python-crumbs-for-cisco-routers-part-i.html)